# Call nested functions from external js file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have to use an external js file in my TS component that it's like this:

```
var myObj;

function setObj(newObj) {
    myObj= newObj;
    return myObj;
}

function my_object() {
    this.getA= function () {
        return this.A;
    }

    this.getB= function () {
        return this.B;
    }

    this.getC = function () {
        return this.C;
    }
}
```

I am able to call the function `setObj` after declaring it this way in my .ts file:

```
declare function setObj(obj: MyObj);
```

But I need to call also the other functions (getA, getB, getC), but I don't know how.
I've tried returning the object when calling setObj and then call the function, like this:

```
let objReturned = setObj(myObj);
objReturned.getA()
```

but it tells me that `getA` is not a function.
How can I call these nested functions inside the js?

Comment: `setObj()` doesn't return anything, and nothing here invokes `my_object()`.  Did you mean to do `let objReturned = new my_object();`?

Comment: As I said, I've added the return for testing purposes, originally it weren't there. Now I've added for clarity. Now I've tried doing as you said but if I do `new my_object();` it tells me  `Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like:

```
declare interface SetObjC {
    getC: () => void;
}
declare interface SetObjB {
    getB: () => SetObjC
}
declare interface SetObjA {
    getA: () => SetObjB;
}
declare function setObj(obj: MyObj): SetObjA;
```